# Insert 100 Record in sql in one query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am using SQL Server 2012.

My question is about to insert 100 or 50 or something like that in one query. I use this query:

```
insert into mystudent(First_Name, Last_Name) 
values('M.Sibtain', 'Zaffar'), ('M.Sibtain', 'Zaffar')
```

I know that it is nonsense to insert 100 different record in one query without changing the column value, but my question here is that how to insert same record 5 or 10 times like repeating the query with one word something like that:

```
insert into mystudent(First_Name, Last_Name) 
values('M.Sibtain','Zaffar') repeat 5
```

Is it possible or is there any such way to do that without executing the query again and again?

Any help will be appreciated.

**Update:** As many users edit my question, so i request to every visitors please try to solve it not to edit it. Thanks

Comment: Which DBMS do you use?

Comment: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/08/29/sql-server-three-methods-to-insert-multiple-rows-into-single-table-sql-in-sixty-seconds-024-video/

Comment: Just a note: in `Sql Server` it is called `row` not `record`.

Comment: Not only in SQL Server, in SQL in general!

Comment: is the data you require accessible from other tables, if so you could do an insert into x select y

Comment: If you can insert the exact same values more than once it seems your schema has some flaws. You should have some sort of constraints so that you don't get the exact same row more than once.

Answer (score 5):

You can do:

```
insert into mystudent(First_Name, Last_Name) 
select top 100 'M.Sibtain','Zaffar' 
from sysobjects
```

For more records, or to be sure, you can cross join:
`from sysobjects a, sysobjects b, sysobjects c`

Answer (score 3):

If you're using SQL Server **Management Studio**, you can use `GO (n)` to achieve this:

```
insert into mystudent(First_Name, Last_Name) 
values('M.Sibtain','Zaffar') 
go 5
```

This will execute this particular `INSERT` five times.

Comment: Works but it is a cursor. On my machine for 100,000 records it took 87 seconds. Also does not work with table variables: after go it is not available.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri: ok ok ok - this is for a **quickie** - it's **NOT** performance-optimized, it's not **pretty** - it's just a quick'n'dirty way to insert 5, 10, 50 rows when you need it ..... don't use in production! .-)

Comment: @webydesigny: why not??

Answer (score 1):

With recursive cte:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
    (
      First_Name NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
      Last_Name NVARCHAR(MAX)
    );
WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   1 AS C
               UNION ALL
               SELECT   C + 1
               FROM     cte
               WHERE    cte.C < 100
             )
    INSERT  INTO @t
            SELECT  'M.Sibtain' ,
                    'Zaffar'
            FROM    cte
    OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: On my machine for 1 million rows it took 8 seconds with capturing statistics and 6 seconds without. SqlFiddle is hanging a lot itself

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE
(
   Id INT IDENTITY(1,1),        
   FirstName NVARCHAR(50),
   LastName NVARCHAR(50)
)
INSERT INTO @tbl
SELECT  'M.Sibtain','Zaffar'

DECLARE 
@number INT

SELECT 
@number = 100 
SELECT  FirstName,LastName
FROM    @tbl t
CROSS APPLY
( SELECT  *
  FROM    master..spt_values m
  WHERE m.number <= @number AND m.number > 0 and m.Type = 'P'
) x
```